# Proper ways to ask for the amount of time for having something

Tags: grammar, expressions, sentence-structure

What would be some proper ways to ask for the amount of time since someone has acquired something. (formal/informal)

Like the question for the following answer:

A: Oh, your puppies are adorable.

**A: ... ?**

B: I have got them for 2 years.

Here's what I could come up with, if they are at all correct:

> A: How long has it been since you've got them?
>
> A: Since when do you have them?

Comment: Those are all ungrammatical.

Comment: "Whenja getim?" "Coupla years ago."  ... "How longya hadim?" "Coupla years I guess."

Comment: @P.E.Dant Nice .. thanks for those expressions bro :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When did you get them?**

> A: Oh, your puppies are adorable.
>
> A: When did you get them?
>
> B: I got them 2 years ago.

Also consider:

**How long have you had them?**

So,

> A: Oh, your puppies are adorable.
>
> A: How long have you had them?
>
> B: I have *had* them for 2 years.

'Had' is a participle of 'to have', which in this case is:

> possess, own, or hold

Of interest: [Uses of "have you had" and "did you have"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58856/uses-of-have-you-had-and-did-you-have)

Answer (score 0):

I would ask:

> **How long have you had them for?**

or

> **Since when have you had them?**

The first asks for the amount of time the person has owned the pet for. A possible reply would be:

> B: *"I have had them for three years."*

The second question asks for the date on which they bought the pet. A possible reply would be:

> B: *"I have had them since July 2014."*